# Finding Co-varying Regions in a 3D Matrix

Tags: cluster-analysis, covariance, correlation, region, areas

I wonder if anyone has a suggestion on how to solve the following problem.

I have a matrix of size n*p*t. I would like to find areas in the plane n*p, that co-vary (in the t dimension).  In other words,  sub-regions on the plane (n*p) whose values vary together along the t dimension.

An example:

`    t=1
    [ 0 0 0
    [ 0 1 1
    [ 0 1 1

```
--->

t=2

[ 3 2 7   
[ 0 2 2   
[ 4 2 2   `
```

So the bottom corner would be assigned to a group since the values co-vary.

Do you have any ideas how to tackle such a problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at biclustering algorithms?